# What's the fastest and easiest way to create a new managed object?

Tags: iphone, core-data

When I have a subclass of NSManagedObject, I could do this:

```
Friend *newFriend = (Friend*)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:@"Friend" 
                                          insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
```

But since I have a subclass, couldn't I simply instantiate it another way so that I don't have to tell it what Entity it is? (I mean: Is there already an predefined initializer for this, or must I write my own?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` the only two methods you can use to customize object initialization are `awakeFromInsert` and `awakeFromFetch`. See the full discussion related to Core Data object initialization [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-SW2).

Comment: But I could write an additional convenience method that would just call internally the -initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: method for me, right?

Comment: Yes, the question is: why would you want to do this?